# How to Lookup multiple Row and Column using PD

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Python and would greatly appreciate if anyone can help please?
I have the following table store as dataframe:

| Age | 2000 | 2010 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 |
| 21 | 0.4 | 0.4 | 0.8 |
| 22 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.5 |

I wanted to be able to Lookup an array of values, so for example I have to lists

```
a = \[20, 20, 21, 22\]

b = \[2000, 2010, 2010, 2020\]
```

I wanted to be able to return the c by looking up the index of

```
\[20, 2000\]

\[20, 2010\]

\[21, 2010\]

\[22, 2020\]
```

So the code returns an array of only 4 numbers. I set the table using dataframe but happy to use any other datatype if available.

I tried several times with index or multi-index but it was not able to return the array. In addition, the multi-index seems to take the value as the index instead of the column title. When I try to lookup using .at and .loc, they return a 4x4 table which isn't what I'm after. What I'm interested in is a 4x1 table. Can any of your experts help please?

Comment: what is your desired output of input? provide in text table or list or something.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Age': {0: 20, 1: 21, 2: 22}, 
         2000: {0: 0.5, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.3},
         2010: {0: 0.6, 1: 0.4, 2: 0.2},
         2020: {0: 0.7, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

a = [20, 20, 21, 22]
b = [2000, 2010, 2010, 2020]
```

df:

```
    Age 2000    2010    2020
0   20  0.5     0.6     0.7
1   21  0.4     0.4     0.8
2   22  0.3     0.2     0.5
```

---

**Code**

You did not provide the desired output and your explanation is not clear. Based on my guess, you might want the following:

use `melt` and `merge`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Age': a, 'variable': b})
out = df1.merge(df.melt('Age'), how='left')
```

out

```
    Age variable    value
0   20  2000        0.5
1   20  2010        0.6
2   21  2010        0.4
3   22  2020        0.5
```

If you want to use the result as a series, `out['value']` is enough, and if you want to create a separate list of results, use the following code:

```
list_out = out['value'].tolist()
```

list_out

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solved my problem, I got exactly what I was looking for ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Age': [20, 21, 22],
  '2000': [0.5, 0.4, 0.3], 
  '2010': [0.6, 0.4, 0.2],
  '2020': [0.7, 0.8, 0.5]
})

a = [20, 20, 21, 22]

b = ['2000', '2010', '2010', '2020']

df = df.set_index('Age')
r = [df.loc[row, col] for row, col in zip(a, b)]

print(r)
```

```
[0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5]
```

**Efficiency** measured using `timeit` module :

Taking into account @Mozway answer on efficiency, we could use `timeit` module for measurement

```
### 1 - Laurent B. : 0.0006105899810791016
### 2 - Mozway 1 : 0.0010399818420410156
### 3 - Panda Kim : 0.012242794036865234
### 4 - Mozway 2 : 0.06174898147583008
```

Comment: As responded to your original comment in my answer, if you provide timings, please time on a large input (e.g., `a = [20, 20, 21, 22]*10_000 ; b = ['2000', '2010', '2010', '2020']*10_000`). Testing on 4 items doesn't make sense.

Comment: it makes sense, it depends on her needs. And on the guessed needs, it's faster

Comment: Thank you, this also works perfectly and for doing the performance testing for me

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient approach is likely to use direct indexing.

Either with [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels). This consists in reordering the DataFrame axes based on the values of `a` and `b`, then convert to numpy array and slice:

```
idx, cols = pd.factorize(np.array(b))

out = (df.set_index('Age')
         .reindex(index=a, columns=cols)
         .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(a)), idx]
      )
```

Output:

```
array([0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5])
```

As a DataFrame:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Age': a, 'Year': b, 'out': out})
```

Output:

```
   Age  Year  out
0   20  2000  0.5
1   20  2010  0.6
2   21  2010  0.4
3   22  2020  0.5
```

Alternatively, using [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and a MultiIndex:

```
out = df.set_index('Age').stack().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a, b]))
```

Output:

```
20  2000    0.5
    2010    0.6
21  2010    0.4
22  2020    0.5
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @LaurentB. have you tested on a large input? It doesn't make sense to time on a small input. It is not smaller doing a quick test on 40k items

Comment: I only test on the inputs she gave. It depends on her needs. So I can't be affirmative on the fact that my proposal is faster in general. Maybe you are right. I don't know.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly as well. Great to know other ways to improve efficiency when I have larger set of data

Answer (score 0):

Use `a = df.to_numpy()`.

Then you can use the
[ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html)
`a` in the usual way, e.g. `a[2, 3]`.
You can also query attributes like `a.shape`, `a.dtype`, and so on.